# Getting a list of all bootable drives mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I'm currently looking for a way to get a list of all the bootable partitions on a Mac?

I know you can get a list of all the volumes? But I don't know how to check if each particular volume is bootable?

Is there a way to do this using **swift** or **objective c**?

Answer (score 0):

With objective-c or swift probably not, but you can run an apple script (terminal commands) from your objective-c app (on OS X, I don't know whether it can be done on iOS)
This is how you execute an apple script:

```
//Begin of the script
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc]
                              initWithSource:@"Tell application \"Terminal\" \n\
                              do shell script \" some script here \"\n\
                              end tell"];
NSDictionary *errors = nil;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:&errors];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
NSLog(@"errors: %@", errors);
if(errors==NULL){

    NSLog(@"Succeeded");

}
else{  

    NSLog(@"Failed");    
}
//End of the script
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way to do this is to shell out to either `bless --info` or `systemsetup liststartupdisks` commands. You can specify that you want the output in plist format to make it easier to parse as well.

As far as executing those commands the typical [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/) should work. You could also use [system()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/system.3.html) I suppose, but it isn't really standard practice on OS X as NSTask has many advantages over it.

A purely code way to do this would be to get the list of disks and then look at each them for the known files that make OS X bootable. Things like the boot.efi file in /System/Library/CoreServices, the mach kernel file, and the contents of /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist.